# Android - contact id is not the selected contact out of the intent

Tags: android, android-intent, android-contacts

When the user needs to select a contact, I call this intent:

```
Intent pickContactIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_PICK,ContactsContract.Contacts.CONTENT_URI );
pickContactIntent.setType(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.CONTENT_TYPE);
startActivityForResult(pickContactIntent, PICK_CONTACT_REQUEST);
```

in onActivityResult I have the following:

```
Uri pickedContact = intent.getData();
Cursor cursor = getContentResolver().query(pickedContact, null, null, null, null);
   if (cursor.moveToFirst()) {
       contactInfo.name = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.Contacts.DISPLAY_NAME));
       contactInfo.photo = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.Contacts.PHOTO_THUMBNAIL_URI));

       Cursor pCur = getContentResolver().query(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.CONTENT_URI,null,
                            ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.CONTACT_ID +" = ?",
                            new String[]{cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.Contacts._ID))}, null);
}
```

While the DISPLAY_NAME and the PHOTO_THUMBNAIL_URI are working as expected, the _ID seems to be of a different contact so the phone numbers cursor retrieves irrelevant phone numbers (of a different contact). What am I missing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `Uri` you specified as the data for the `Intent` does not match the mimetype you have set.

For the data you used `Contacts.CONTENT_URI`, which has the mimetype `Contacts.CONTENT_TYPE` (whose value is "vnd.android.cursor.dir/contact"). For the mimetype, you set it as `CommonDataKinds.Phone.CONTENT_TYPE` (whose value is "vnd.android.cursor.dir/phone_v2"), which is normally associated with the Uri `CommonDataKinds.Phone.CONTENT_URI`.

What's happening is you are actually picking a Phone, so you are getting back a content Uri of a Phone instead of a Contact. This is not apparent when you extract the display name and thumbnail photo Uri, because those columns come from the contact anyway when you query for a Phone. However, the _ID is for that of the Phone, not the Contact.

Change your code to

`pickContactIntent.setType(Contacts.CONTENT_TYPE)`

...or just remove the call to `setType()` altogether, since the system will resolve it anyway.

Comment: Thanks it worked. One question though, you wrote "This is not apparent when you extract the display name and thumbnail photo Uri, because those columns come from the contact anyway": does it mean I can get this info using the phone number cursor instead of querying it twice as I do now?

Comment: Yes, you could get it from the query for the phone number. That could save you a query if you pulled the contact ID from the Uri instead of doing the first query (e.g. using `ContentUris.parseId(intent.getData())`)